# How can I animate Label.Content with a DoubleAnimation?

Tags: wpf, animation, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

A DoubleAnimation changes a double value over time. I would like to set the Content property of a Label to this value. However, this fails because WPF does not convert the double to a string.

Do I have to subclass the Label and add a new double propery, which is bound to the Content, and let the DoubleAnimation change this new property? Or is there an easier way?

The double value in question is not limited to certain values, i.e. fixed StringKeyframes cannot be used.

**Example use case:** A countdown timer with extended precision, which displays the remaining time in a Label.

Comment: I'm sure this is a pretty stupid question, but I've not found an answer after half an hour of googling.

Comment: What do you mean "animate"?  Just change the text displayed?  Couldn't you do that by just binding "Content" to your property?

Comment: @McGarnagle Yes, I could - but I would need to create this property first. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: @mafu Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: @lll I feel it is too complicated for such a simple task. To my understanding, this would involve a) subclassing the Label b) adding a new double property ("NumericValue"), whose `set` would edit the Content and c) adding a NumericValueProperty (similar to `Label.OpacityProperty` etc.) so the animation can actually access it. I suppose 20 or 30 lines of code?

Comment: @mafu My 2 cents is that, if you are coming as a web developer you'll experience that in WPF some cases looks complicated for such a simple task and some cases you'll realize that WPF does more heavy lifting and makes it simple than doing it with HTML/JS.

Answer (score 2):

Set the Label `ContentStringFormat="{}{0}"`, or use a TextBox and set `StringFormat` in the Text binding.

Comment: I've just tried setting ContentStringFormat but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I used:
`lbl.ContentStringFormat = "{}{0}";
lbl.Content = "test";
var anim = new DoubleAnimation (10, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds (10));
lbl.BeginAnimation (Label.ContentProperty, anim);`

This throws an AnimationException: Specified cast is not valid. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you were doing it in XAML. The others are correct, you'll need to create a Double dependency property or use one on an existing control.

Incidentally why are you trying to do this in code-behind? This isn't WinForms, and honestly you're going to have a world of headache if you keep going down the path you are. What you should be doing is creating a view model and binding your view controls to that.

Comment: Ah, too bad. I've just tried to set everything in XAML instead of codebehind, but it failed with the same exception. Thank you for the hint, I'm still learning WPF and will read up on it.

Comment: No problem, good luck! [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) will get you started, [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple) is good too.